# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined - but site works accurately - Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined
```

My app renders fine in the browser, but I get this error in the Chrome console that I'd like to understand/fix.
Console gives the error 3 times, directing to the file/line `CurrentWeatherComponent.html:3` which is `<span>{{current.city}}, {{current.country}} </span>`

if I remove `{{current.city}},` it will give the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined`
Thing is, in the browser the app actually renders the `current` city, `current` country, `current` date, and all other properties of `current` just fine.
Since the error is printed three times in the console but then renders just fine I am guessing it has to do with timing?

Below code for completeness. Let me know if (and what) I need to post for more detail.

HTML:

```
current-weather.component.html:
<div>
  <div>
    <span>{{current.city}}, {{current.country}} </span>
    <span>{{current.date | date:'fullDate'}}</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img [src]='current.image'>
    <span>{{current.temperature | number: '1.0-0'}}℉</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    {{current.description}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Component:

```
current-weather.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { ICurrentWeather } from '../interfaces'
import { WeatherService } from '../weather/weather.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-current-weather',
  templateUrl: './current-weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./current-weather.component.css'],
})
export class CurrentWeatherComponent implements OnInit {
  current: ICurrentWeather

  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.weatherService
      .getCurrentWeather('Hilversum', 'NL')
      .subscribe(data => (this.current = data))
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use `?` such as `{{current?.city}}`

Comment: @ABOS Yes, that does work! But it does not seem that 'elegant'?

Comment: otherwise you have to do a more  "conventional" way, something like `{{current && current.city}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until the moment the `weatherService.getCurrentWeather` function emits `data`, `this.current` is `undefined` and therefore you see these errors in the console.

You can either use `{{current?.city}}` and do the same for all other properties of `current`. Or you can wait with rendering all elements that use `current` until it is available, by using an `*ngIf` attribute:

```html
<div *ngIf="current">
  <div>
    <span>{{current.city}}, {{current.country}} </span>
    <span>{{current.date | date:'fullDate'}}</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img [src]='current.image'>
    <span>{{current.temperature | number: '1.0-0'}}℉</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    {{current.description}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: definitely works! So for now I'll use this. But it still feels like a work-around. Isn't there an elegant way to say "wait till data is emitted" ?

Comment: @jbr870 In general, no. For some cases the `async` pipe might be nice.